# Perl read file returning only partial lines

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script to rename files based on a given list.  To test to make sure the list is read correct, I have:

```
print("start\n");
open(READFILE, "<prune.txt") || die "Couldn't open file";
print("file open\n");
while ($curline = <READFILE>){

print "$curline\n";
}
close (READFILE);
```

if my list file is

```
P_4
IMG_0531
PICT0009
IMG_0416
RAY HASSMAN GROUP 015
P_5
```

then my output is

```
P_5 HASSMAN GROUP 015
```

Why am I getting this weird mess?

As asked here is the hex dump of my input file

```
0000: 50 5F 34 0D 49 4D 47 5F   P_4¬IMG_
0008: 30 35 33 31 0D 50 49 43   0531¬PIC
0010: 54 30 30 30 39 0D 49 4D   T0009¬IM
0018: 47 5F 30 34 31 36 0D 52   G_0416¬R
0020: 41 59 20 48 41 53 53 4D   AY HASSM
0028: 41 4E 20 47 52 4F 55 50   AN GROUP
0030: 20 30 31 35 0D 50 5F 35    015¬P_5
```

I am using Mac 10.9.2 build 13c39

Comment: Is there any tab character in the file? Also, you `chomp` $_, but do not use it afterwards.

Comment: whoops using an old version of the code.  just updated it.  Still get P_5 HASSMAN GROUP 015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of line ending characters, your script produces `"\r"` characters that move the cursor to the leftmost position, but do not advance a line. Therefore, all the information is overwriting itself over and over. I cannot imagine how this can happen with literal `"\n"` in the code - are you sure the code you posted produces the output? What OS are you on? Can you post a hexdump of the input file?

Comment: Ok I added the dump to my OP

Comment: Yes, it is as I guessed. If you `print "a\x0db"`, Perl will print `a`, return back left and overwrite the `a` with `b`.

Comment: ok so I should go into the list file using a regex program (text wrangler) and do a s#\r#\n#g ?

Comment: @traisjames: Try that. You can use Perl to change the file, BTW.